# Blocking calls & linux scheduler

Tags: sockets, networking, io, blocking

Does Linux scheduler hand of control flow to a different process while current one is waiting on select(), poll() or other socket operations in synchronous (blocking) mode? What is the status of process while it's waiting? How exactly is it waken up?

there is a version that process is in a 'sleeping' state, it's waken up by kernel wakeup with WCHAN, and yes, the operating system will schedule other processes to run while one is blocked on IO. is that variant correct? Do you know what should / can I read these things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. Usually when a process executes the system call it voluntarily calls schedule and waits on the pages in memory (which are going to be read in the I/O). In the I/O completion handler it releases the locks on this page which remove the waiting process from the wait queue and place them back onto the run queue where they can continue to execute. I think that operating systems books should cover it if you're willing to read into it but I would just look at the code :)

Comment: Honestly, I did look at the code. Kernel code is not the easiest thing to grasp from the first time. I'll try again though. Thanks

Comment: @ifesdjeen Specifically you can look into end_bio_read and the read() and write() system call paths that go into the VFS. It does get kind of complicated so if you want an overall view I would go with a standard university OS textbook.

Comment: well, I have read through Understanding Linux Kernel and Linux Programming Interface to get a bit more knowledge. And I *think* i have read about waking up of the process in one of those. I would appreciate if you could suggest more things to read. I think that is a very important topic for every programmer.

Comment: Professional Linux Kernel Architecture by Wolfgang Maurer and Understanding the Linux Kernel for starters (forgot author on this one)

Comment: @ifesdjeen I recommend the first one as it is way more in depth than understanding the linux kernel and essentially covers everything in understanding the linux kernel anyway.